# 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll Additional information: Not a valid file name

Tags: c#

This is my code.
The file name is correct, I don't know what is the problem. I have checked everything, I couldn't find the cause, if anybody could help me that would be awesome

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel; 
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace Car
{
    public partial class AddCar : Form
    {
        OleDbConnection cnnOLEDB = new OleDbConnection();
        OleDbCommand cmdInsert = new OleDbCommand();
        public AddCar()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void AddCar_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { // i use access 2013 
         //the address of file is exactly the same as here
            cnnOLEDB.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data     Source=‪C:\database\LOGIN.accdb;";
            cnnOLEDB.Open();
            //the error exactly shows here
        }

        private void InstButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(txtFullName.Text != "" && txtPIC.Text != "" && txtEmail.Text != "" && txtHP.Text != "" && txtAddress.Text != "" && txtAmount.Text != "" && txtDOR.Text != "" && txtDORE.Text != "")
            {
                cmdInsert.CommandText = "INSERT INTO MemN(FullName, PICNO, Email, HP, Address, Amount, DOR, DORE) VALUES (\'" + txtFullName.Text + "\' , \'" + txtPIC.Text + "\' , \'" + txtEmail.Text + "\' , " + txtHP.Text + " , \'" + txtAddress.Text + "\' , \'" + txtAmount.Text + "\' , \'" + txtDOR.Text + "\' , \'" + txtDORE.Text + "\');";
                cmdInsert.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmdInsert.Connection = cnnOLEDB;
                MessageBox.Show("Customer added.");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Customer is not added successfully!");
            }

            cmdInsert.Dispose();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove the spaces in excess between Data and Source, leave just one. And single quotes doesn't need to be escaped, in any case use the answer that suggest to apply parameters (but not with AddWithValue to avoid errors in string conversions) Finally NEXT TIME, NEVER WRITE **ASAP** in your question because yours school problems are only yours

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should use `parameterized` sql to prevent `sql injection`.

You have not given qoutes around the value of `HP` surround it with qoutes.

```
cmdInsert.CommandText = "INSERT INTO MemN(FullName, PICNO, Email, HP, Address, Amount, DOR, DORE) VALUES (\'" + txtFullName.Text + "\' , \'" + txtPIC.Text + "\' , \'" + txtEmail.Text + "\' , \'" + txtHP.Text + "\' , \'" + txtAddress.Text + "\' , \'" + txtAmount.Text + "\' , \'" + txtDOR.Text + "\' , \'" + txtDORE.Text + "\');";
```

You can use parameterized query like this

```
cmdInsert.CommandText = "INSERT INTO MemN(FullName, PICNO, Email, HP, Address, Amount, DOR, DORE) VALUES (@FullName, @PICNO, @Email, @HP, @Address, @Amount, @DOR, @DORE);";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FullName", txtFullName.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PICNO", txtPIC.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtEmail.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HP", txtHP.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", txtAddress.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Amount", txtAmount.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DOR", txtDOR.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DORE", txtDORE.Text);
```

Comment: thx man for your time , i did this , but still i get the same error that the file name is not valid

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Not a valid file name. and it shows cnnOLEDB.open(); by yellow color

Comment: Is you file `accdb` or `mdb` ?

Comment: the file is accdb , and the exact address is ‪C:\database\LOGIN.accdb

Comment: Chnage file name and check